GODOT: I can't start projects in mobile or forward
I'm learning godot 4.2.2 and I'm trying to start and edit a new project in mobile or +forward rendering and it won't let me, it just closes, I've tried other projects but it doesn't work either, the console gives me this error:
WARNING: Blend file import is enabled in the project settings, but no Blender path is configured in the editor settings. Blend files will not be imported.
     at: _editor_init (modules/gltf/register_types.cpp:63)
ERROR: Caller thread can't call this function in this node (/root). Use call_deferred() or call_thread_group() instead.
   at: propagate_notification (scene/main/node.cpp:2249)

================================================================
handle_crash: Program crashed with signal 11
Engine version: Godot Engine v4.2.2.stable.official (15073afe3856abd2aa1622492fe50026c7d63dc1)
Dumping the backtrace. Please include this when reporting the bug to the project developer.
[1] /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3c770) [0x7de917751770] (??:0)
-- END OF BACKTRACE --
================================================================



La informacion de mi sistema es:
OS: Artix Linux x86_64
Kernel: 6.9.4-artix1-1
CPU: Intel Xeon L5420 (4) @ 2.493GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 520
I tried creating the project in compatibility and if it starts, which makes me believe that the problem is my graphics, I just don't know what to do, I looked in forums for similar problems but there doesn't seem to be anyone with my same error or if so they seem to solve it by just restarting

It seems the import from blender setting is enabled but you haven't given it the correct path, I'd recommend doing either of 2 things:

if your project is not using 3D assets imported from blender then simply go to project settings > FileSystem > Import and uncheck the blender enabled setting



if your project does use 3D assets imported from blender then follow the steps make sure you're blender path is correct, This video should guide you through that process


the problem is not that warning, it is the ERROR that causes it to close ERROR: Caller thread can't call this function in this node (/root). Use call_deferred() or call_thread_group() instead. 

@Smilee my apologies I didn't see that properly, as for the error I think it might be a bug you should look into this github issue
